# Getting pay pal transaction ID after payment was successful

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm using react pay-pal express checkout for my react js app. I'm followed the documentation and it works perfectly. However, It does not return the transaction ID. Only paymentID,payerID etc works as expected on the documentation but not the Transaction ID. Here is the link of the paypal express checkout: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-express-checkout/v/1.0.5.

```
  const onSuccess = (payment) => {
      console.log("Transaction ID!", payment.transactions[0] 
     ['related_resources'][0]['sale']['id']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the log of the entire response content about whether the Transaction ID is inside.

- If yes, I think you can soon figure out where goes wrong.
- If not, you can refer to below link, where the Transaction ID can actually be obtained through Payment ID with another request (as you mentioned, the Payment ID is already obtained): 
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/#search-payment-details

Comment: I already did that checking on the log does not contain transaction ID on the return object. As per documentation on Sample Returned Data on this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-express-checkout/v/1.0.5. Only that object information return.